# in django is it possible to have a two part form with some repeating fields?

Tags: django

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zGk9.png)I would like to have a form with a few fields that will repeat themselves Django

a django form with a few fields that have multiple entries

Comment: What do you mean with multiple entries? Multiple fields that have the same name? Can you show an example? Also, please add what you've tried so far.

Comment: Do you want to repeat Form2?